# How to create mac style tabs in a qt application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I have created tabs using qtabwidget in my application. But it looks like normal tab, not as mac osx safari preferences or vlc preferences or firefox preferences tabs with large icons and the text at the bottom of those icons.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [setDocumentMode](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#documentMode-prop) on your qTabBar to accomplish this.

Comment: SetDocumentMode is set True and the icon size is increased to 64 x 64. But the tab text is not going down the icon. As well as the tabs are not growing with respect to icon size which is set to the tabs.   Hence the icons are automatically placed outside the tabs, but inside the tabwidget.   Sorry i could not upload its screen shot as i need few more points to do it here.